# How to programmatically set "PreviousPageType VirtualPath" (for "Server.Transfer" to one page from multiple pages)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I want to have one page shown for a couple of pages using `Server.Transfer` (e.g. if the user navigates to page1 or page2 - it will, in both cases, show him page3). I am doing that because the pages are very similar.

However, there are a couple of differences between them, which I want to take care of getting the public properties of the sending page (e.g. page1 or page2) as shown [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx) in the fourth option.

But that needs the `PreviousPageType VirtualPath` to be set to the correct page - which might be one of several (e.g. page1 or page2). How do I do that?

EDIT: It's a web application project.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1438300.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an alternate way to ur problem using `Object.GetType()` method to find out from which page you call `server.transfer` method.

**This is code in page_load of page3**

```
    Object prePage=PreviousPage;
    String gotprePage=prePage.GetType().ToString();
    if (gotprePage == "ASP.crosspage3_aspx")
    {
        //now call properties specific to crosspage3.aspx page
        // prePage.GetType().GetProperty("your_property").
        //GetValue(objPreviousPage, null).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        if (gotprePage == "ASP.crosspage4_aspx")
        {
            //now call properties specific to crosspage4.aspx page
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer for now. But if you know of a way of actually setting the `PreviousPageType VirtualPath` - that would be the real answer.

Comment: @ispiro did you find a better solution, or is this answer still as the only way to accomplish this goal

Comment: @ViROscar I have not found a better solution.